# Confused with web / worker roles and instances in windows azure.

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I am new to Windows Azure and confused about web / worker roles and instances. I plan on deploying a web application that uses WCF services for the back end. I have a few questions:

1. Am I correct in saying that I need one web role to host the web app and another secondary web or worker role to host internal WCF services?
2. How many instances of each should I start with? Is it a good idea to have two instances of each web / worker role i.e. incase one is unavailable?
3. I would imagine having more than one instance also allows for automatic load balancing?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in saying that I need one web role to host the web app
>   and another secondary web or worker role to host internal WCF
>   services?

Yes. Web Roles are suitable for hosting web applications (websites, web services etc.) and Worker Roles are suitable for hosting background applications which does not require user interaction (think of them as hosting `Services` like applications running on your local computer).

> How many instances of each should I start with? Is it a good idea to
>   have two instances of each web / worker role i.e. in case one is
>   unavailable?

Yes. In fact to get SLA guarantee from Microsoft, you would need to have 2 instances of your role running.

> I would imagine having more than one instance also allows for
>   automatic load balancing?

Yes. By default all web role instances are load-balanced using round-robin load balancing. AFAIK, worker role instances are not load balanced.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think if you have internal wcf services in a web role they won't be load balanced either...?

Comment: Web roles are load balanced.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to have separate roles if you don't need to scale them separately http://stackoverflow.com/q/6266560/57428

Comment: @GauravMantri have a look at this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747863/how-to-host-wcf-service-programmatically-on-azure/10747994#10747994 If they are on a internal endpoint they will not be load balanced?

Comment: @sharptooth I wasn't aware that you could actually do that might be worthwhile to start off like that and save some $$$ do you have any links to on how to do this?

Comment: @CoolBreeze You don't need any links for that. Just put the infinite loop from the worker role `Run()` into the web role `Run()`. The deal is a web role is a worker role with IIS enabled, that's all the difference.

Comment: Makes sense but what if I want to have a wcf service web role and website in a single web role?

Comment: @CoolBreeze I haven't tried this myself, but I guess you can configure them on different ports and open up two different endpoints for them.